# Does Javascript engine see constant variables in advance?

Tags: javascript, v8

Consider this chunk of code

```
function getPow() {
    const a = 2
    return Math.pow(2, a)
}
```

If `a` is a constant and it's not used by anything but the `pow` function, will the javascript engine evaluate the math equasion in advance (creational phase) and put the results in `return` or the function will do the computation every time it's invoked?

And is it the same for all engines (V8, SpiderMonkey, etc...)?

Comment: Does it really matter? Also, I really doubt it'd execute the `pow()`. It might inline the `a`, though but...so what?

Comment: Many compilers do this in advance in the code optimization phase.

Comment: I have simplified the math function for the question, in my case, it's a very expensive function so it does matter. @VLAZ

Comment: @DedaDev then are you asking if JS will do a *function call* in advance or are you asking if it will *evaluate a mathematical expression* in advance?

Comment: @VLAZ mathematical expression

Comment: And you've verified it is an actual bottleneck?

Comment: @DedaDev, for anyone who wonders if this matters. Please don't focus on the toy example used here for illustration. Consider the case where you have a complex function that does many things in 1200 directions, where 1000 are constant or partially constant expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, V8's optimizing compiler supports "constant folding" (i.e. performing calculations at compile time when their inputs are known at compile time), and this optimization does trigger for the example in the question.

It doesn't matter whether `const a` is used for anything else or not.

While it's probably true that all engines do this, it's also an internal implementation detail, and I wouldn't recommend to rely on it (in any engine). It also shouldn't really matter, in most cases.

Comment: Thanks, is there any documentation on things that V8 does at compile time?

Comment: No, these are internal details that keep changing. In particular, whether a given function gets optimized at all is a decision that the engine makes dynamically based on a variety of changing factors.

Answer (score 0):

If you want part of a math expression to be precalculated outside of a function invocation you can do something like this:

```
const a = 2;

const myPow = Math.pow(2, a);

function getPow() {
  return myPow;
}
```

Alternatively, if you wish to delay the running of the calculation until the first invocation you could use something like this:

```
const a = 2;

let _myPow;

function myPow() {
  if (_myPow === undefined) {
     _myPow = Math.pow(2, a);
  }
  return _myPow;
}

function getPow() {
  return myPow();
}
```